# Want label.with value on horizontal line

Tags: pine-script

I have written a code for horizontal line which will tale input and based on input value horizontal line will come .but I need a label and value at horizontal line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a `label` and set its `y` value to your `hline`'s price value.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)


h = input(30000)

hline(h, color=color.blue, linestyle=hline.style_solid)

var label h_label = label.new(bar_index, h, "Line Value: " + str.tostring(h))

label.set_x(h_label, bar_index)
```

[image]

Comment: in this way we dont have enable & disable check box , in my case it has that facility . if i dint need that value i shoud be unchecking that so that line will not display . here we dont have such option

Comment: You cannot do this that way. A workaround is add a `bool` user input and plot if the checkbox is checked. So, you would have your checkbox in the inputs section.

Comment: Can u help me with a sample code for one input value with work around mentioned